# Is there a way to pass vector in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am very new to R programming. I am trying to create a small loop where I am passing numbers (1 and 2) to `asdf`.

```
for (i in c(4,28)){
  asdf = i
}
```

Expected output

```
asdf
4
28
```

Is there a way to achieve the above result

Comment: Avoid the loop.  `asdf <- c(4, 28)`.

Answer (score -1):

A loop works iteratively, so in your code in the last iteration you overwrite the previous value in the vector asdf and assign it the new value of 28.

If you want to store both values in the vector, you first initialize an empty vector. For each iteration then, append the value of interest to the already existing vector. As detailed in the code below:

```
asdf <- c() #initialize empty vector

for (i in c(4,28)){
asdf <- c(asdf, i)
}
```

**Output:**

```
> asdf
[1]  4 28
```

Comment: Recursively appending to a vector (`asdf <- c(asdf, ...)`) is slow and expensive, because it copies the vector every time. If you already know which items you want the vector to hold, just do `asdf <- c(4, 28)`, as @Limey indicated in his comment. One of R's strengths is its vectoring capabilities. More often than not, `for` loops aren't a good solution in R.

Comment: Also, iteratively growing the vector inside a loop is *very* inefficient.  If you *must* do it this way, create a vector of the required length *before* you execute the loop and then access each element individually, rather than extending by concatenation.

Comment: @Limey AFAIK, the JIT compiler can optimize that issue away. But of course it's better to use best practices.